# Set Airflow Variable dynamically

Tags: python, airflow, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-composer

Hi community I need for help.
I have a GCS bucket called "staging". This bucket contain folders and subfolders (see picture).
[image]

The "date-folders" (eg. 20221128) may be several. Each date-folder has 3 subfolders: I'm interested in the "main_folder". The main_folder has 2 "project folders". Each project folder has several subfolders. Each of these last subfolder has a .txt file.

The main objective is:

1. Obtain a list of all the path to .txt files (eg. gs://staging/20221128/main_folder/project_1/subfold_1/file.txt, ...)
2. Export the list on an Airflow Variable
3. Use the "list" Variable to run some DAGS dynamically.

The folders in the staging bucket may vary everyday, so I don't have static paths.
I'm using Apache Beam with Python SDK on Cloud Dataflow and Airflow with Cloud Composer.

Is there a way to obtain the list of paths (as `os.listdir()` on python) with Beam and schedule this workflow daily? (I need to override the list Variable eveyday with new paths).

For example I can achieve step n.1 (locally) with the following Python script:

```
def collect_paths(startpath="C:/Users/PycharmProjects/staging/"):
list_paths = []
for path, dirs, files in os.walk(startpath):
    for f in files:
        file_path = path + "/" + f
        list_paths .append(file_path )
return list_paths
```

Thank you all in advance.

Edit n.1.

I've retrieved file paths thanks to google.cloud.storage API in my `collect_paths` script. Now, I want to access to XCom and get the list of paths. This is my task instance:

```
    collect_paths_job = PythonOperator(
       task_id='collect_paths',
       python_callable=collect_paths,
       op_kwargs={'bucket_name': 'staging'},
       do_xcom_push=True
    )
```

I want to iterate over the list in order to run (in the same DAG) N concurrent task, each processing a single file. I tried with:

```
files = collect_paths_job.xcom_pull(task_ids='collect_paths', include_prior_dates=False)
for f in files:
    job = get_job_operator(f)
    chain(job)
```

But got the following error:

```
TypeError: xcom_pull() missing 1 required positional argument: 'context'
```

Comment: I don't quite understand how this would involve Dataflow or Beam. The airflow DAG is scheduling the Dataflow job, yes? I am just asking since I know about Beam but I do not know as much about Airflow. I think your solution will be in the Airflow not the Beam.

Comment: I don’t really understand your need, you want to launch a DAG for each file dynamically ?

Comment: @MazlumTosun I have a bucket that is filled everyday with new folders/subfolders and files. I need to retrieve the gcs path of each file and pass them as a list of paths to an Airflow instance to run a DAG for each file

Comment: @KennKnowles Airflow and Beam (Composer/Dataflow) are the tools can I use. My problem is how to get the list of paths from GCS in order to run DAGs dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to correct you in your usage of the term `Variable` . Airflow attributes a special meaning to this object. What you want is for the file info to be accessible as parameters in a task.

#### Use XCom

Assume you have the DAG with the python task called -- `list_files_from_gcs`.
This task is a python task which exactly runs the `collect_path` function that you have written. Since this function returns a list, airflow automatically stuffs this into XCom. So now you can access this information anywhere in your DAG in subsequent tasks.

1. Now your subsequent task can again be a python task in the **same DAG** which case you can access XCom very very easily:

   ```
   @task
   def next_task(xyz, abc, **context):
       ti = context['ti']
       files_list = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='list_files_from_gcs')
       ...
       ...
   ```
2. If you are now looking to call an entirely different DAG now, then you can use `TriggerDagRunOperator` as well and pass this list as `dag_run` config like this:

   ```
   TriggerDagRunOperator(
       conf={
           "gcs_files_list": "{{task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='list_files_from_gcs'}}"
       },
       ....
       ....
   )
   ```

   Then your triggered DAG can just parse the DAG run config to move ahead.

Comment: Once I have the list in "xcom_pull" i need to iterate over paths and run a task for each file. Tasks are all the same, but they must work in parallel on different file. How can I iterate over the list and create a DAG with N tasks dinamically?